# Group first by category, then by week or month

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My documents looks like this:

```
{
    category: "1",
    timestamp: ISODate("2016-07-16T00:00:00.000Z"),
    amount: 0
},
{
    category: "1",
    timestamp: ISODate("2016-08-18T00:00:00.000Z"),
    amount: 15
},
{
    category: "1",
    timestamp: ISODate("2016-08-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    amount: 5
},
{
    category: "2",
    timestamp: ISODate("2016-08-18T00:00:00.000Z"),
    amount: 10
}
```

Now I'd like to **first** group by category (which already works):

```
{ "$match" : { "timestamp" : { "$gt" : FROM , "$lt" : TO }}},
{ "$sort" : { "timestamp" : 1 }},
{ "$group" : {
    "_id" : "$category",
    "data" : { "$push" : { "timestamp" : "$timestamp" , "amount" : "$amount" }}
}}
```

And **then** group those objects within the `data` array. To get *the max amount for each week* (or month - depending on user input).

The result then should look something like this (when grouping by month):

```
{
    _id: "1",
    data: [
        {
            timestamp: "2016-07",    // could also be an ISODate with
            amount: 0                // first (or last) day of month
        },                           // if that makes things easier
        {
            timestamp: "2016-08",
            amount: 15
        }
    ]
},
{
    _id: "2",
    data: [
        {
            timestamp: "2016-08",
            amount: 10
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to `unwind` the `data` array and then grouping again, but that resulted in a total mess.

Hope you've got some nice idea / solution to get this working.

**EDIT: Additional Question:**

I've put an index on `category` which works just fine for `$match`. Would it also be useful to put an index on `timestamp` for sorting (because the insertion ordering can differ from the timestamp ordering) or won't this index have any effect within the aggregation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've taken Styvane's answer (thanks again!) and simplified it a bit:

```
{$match: { timestamp: { $gt: FROM , $lt: TO }}},
{$group: {
    _id: {
        id: "$category",
        timestamp: { $concat: [
            { $toLower: { $year:"$timestamp" } },
            "-",
            { $toLower: { $month: "$timestamp" } }
        ] }
    },
    amount: { $max: "$amount" }
}},
{$sort: { "_id.timestamp": 1 } },
{$group: {
    _id: "$_id.id",
    data: { $push: { timestamp: "$_id.timestamp", amount: "$amount" } }
}}
```

I tried to `$sort` before the first `$group` but that did give sometimes unexpected results. Though I just placed the `$sort` between the `$group` stages. This way having an index on `timestamp` doesn't matter anymore.

Answer (score 1):

After the `$sort` stage, you need to `$group` by "category" then `$unwind` the "data" field.

```
var group1 = { "$group": { 
    "_id": "$category", 
    "data": { 
        "$push": { 
            "timestamp": "$timestamp", 
            "amount": "$amount"
        }
    }
}};

var unwind = { "$unwind": "$data"};
```

From there, you need to re`$group` your documents, but this time you need to consider not only the `timestamp` field but the `_id` field as well and with the help of the `$toLower` operator you can convert the year and the month value to string which you can concatenate using the `$concat` operator.

You also return the sum of that group with `$sum`.

```
var group2 = { "$group": { 
    "_id": { 
        "id": "$_id", 
        "timestamp": { 
            "$concat": [ 
                { "$toLower": { "$year": "$data.timestamp" } }, 
                "-", 
                { "$toLower": { "$month": "$data.timestamp" } }
            ]
    }}, 
    "amount": { "$sum": "$data.amount" }
}}
```

Last stage is another `$group` stage where you simply group the your document by previous `_id.id` value and use the `$push` accumulator operator to return the array of data.

```
var group3 = { "$group": { 
    "_id": "$_id.id", 
    "data": { 
        "$push": { 
            "timestamp": "$_id.timestamp", 
            "amount": "$amount" 
        }
    }
}};
```

Your final pipeline will look like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        // $match and `$sort here
        group1,
        unwind,
        group2,
        group3
    ]
)
```

This query can be improved in the upcoming version of MongoDB using the `$facet` operator.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    // $match and `$sort here
    { "$facet": { "data": [ group1, unwind, group2, group3 ] }
])
```

Comment: Wow! thank you! I'll go through it later and try it. Do you have any opinion on creating an Index on the timestamp field for sorting?

Comment: I added an own answer based on your code. It does the grouping on the collection itself, though no need for `group1` and `unwind`. But now the `$sort` right after the `$match` didn't give the expected results. I can't explain this happens. Though I put the `$sort` between the `$group` stages.